# How to move a file and change its name without retyping the name and just add the new characters

Tags: bash, command-line, rename, mv

I change too frequently the location of some files generated daily. The thing is that I want to change their names by only adding the new required characters.

What I want is something like this:

```
$ mv file.csv /home/user/{something}_backup1
```

So I could see:

```
$ ls /home/user
file.csv_backup1
```

What I'm doing now is the simple:

```
$ mv file.csv /home/user/file.csv_backup1
```

You could say "don't be lazy and do it that way", the thing is that the real file names have around 25 characters and retyping them is really annoying.

The past given is only an example, it could be a different directory or different new text.

By the way I'm using bash shell

Comment: You should specify what shell you are using.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) or [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) function added in your shell rc file :

```
mymv(){ echo mv "$1" "$2/${1##*/}_$3"; }
mymv file.csv /home/user backup1
```

remove the `echo` when tests are done

Comment: But this is specific for the example given, I want something general cause it could be a different destination directory and different extra text

Comment: POST edited accordingly

Answer (score 3):

The simplest route, IMHO, is to use a variable:

```
a=file.csv; mv "$a" ~user/"$a"_backup
```

You can avail of tab completion with variables, both while setting them and while using them.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`, you could try the following:

- Type `mv file1`.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> enough times to delete `file1`.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl-y</kbd> to paste `file1` back.
- Type `/home/user/`.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl-y</kbd> to paste `file1`.
- Type the rest: `_backup`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution.

A little crude, but this is going to work if all the original files are going to have the extension `.csv` and if you want to move all the `.csv` files from the current directory.

```
for i in *.csv; do 
    mv $i /home/user; 
    rename .csv .csv_backup1 /home/user/*.csv; 
done
```

Just change the 'user' for each users when needed.

Comment: @muru Thanks for correcting. Any reason you said 'never parse the output of `ls` ?

Comment: Consider what will happen, if you have a file named `a  b.csv`. And for a full discussion: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls (Accordingly, other things in your answer need changing, such as quoting of `$i`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make simple script in home folder(or any folder other than the folder which contains the files you are intending to move). The script will be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in ./*
do
if [ -f "$var" ]
then
mv "$var" /home/user/"$var".backup1
fi
done
```

- run this script inside the folder from which you are intending to move files i.e. by `cd <the directory your files are in>` and then run this script
- this script will move all files to `/home/user` and will change the name accordingly
- if the filenames contain `spaces`  no problem
- it will also make sure that its moving only files not directory so that you dont get any error message or unexpected result